# Acceleration data calculate the distance

Tags: python, android

this is my first question I ask.
My problem is have have used an android studio app to get the data of the acceleration sensor from my smartphone. Now I want to calculate the distance that I have covered and reconstruct the way I have walked. I walked in a 15x7 meters rectangle. I turned at every corner about 90 degrees, took a 2s break and then walked the next way. How can I do this? I have tried in many ways but it just seems to be not working...
thanks for the help :)
~Jumbo

My Code I used to calculate the distance

```
`
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import scipy.io.wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lowpass(data: np.ndarray, cutoff: float, sample_rate: float, poles: int = 5):
    sos = scipy.signal.butter(poles, cutoff, 'lowpass', fs=sample_rate, output='sos')
    filtered_data = scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
    return filtered_data

filename = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
print(filename)
#img = Image.open(filename)
df =pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';', decimal=",") 
df.columns = ["t[s]", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"]
#df.drop('Column6', axis=1)
#df.drop('Column5', axis=1)
#df = pd.read_excel(r"ETF_Sparplan.xlsx", sheet_name="WatchNew")

print(df)

df_t =  df['t[s]'] #df['Column1']
df_x = df['Column2']
df_y = df['Column3']
df_z = df['Column4']
df_x -= -0.04
df_y -= -0.00800
df_z -= -0.06643

# auf 100 Hz umrechnen
t_new = np.linspace(0, int(math.ceil(df_t.max())), math.ceil(df_t.max())*100+1)

x_new = np.interp(t_new, df_t, df_x)
y_new = np.interp(t_new, df_t, df_y)
z_new = np.interp(t_new, df_t, df_z)

x_filtered = lowpass(df_x, 2, 100)
y_filtered = lowpass(df_y, 2, 100)
z_filtered = lowpass(df_z, 2, 100)

x_new_filtered = lowpass(x_new, 2, 100)
y_new_filtered = lowpass(y_new, 2, 100)
z_new_filtered = lowpass(z_new, 2, 100)

#df = df.sort_values('Bezeichnung')
#
#kandidaten_liste = df.Bezeichnung.dropna().unique()
#ser_kandidaten_liste = pd.Series(kandidaten_liste)
#ser_kandidaten_liste.to_pickle('kandidaten_list.pkl'


plt.plot(df_t, df_x, 'r')
plt.plot(df_t, df_y, 'g')
plt.plot(df_t, df_z, 'b')
plt.title("Beschleunigungswerte Ungefiltert")
plt.xlabel("t[s]")
#plt.xlim(1.1, 1.45)
plt.ylabel("a[m/s^2]")
plt.show()

#plt.plot(df_t, x_filtered, 'r')
#plt.plot(df_t, y_filtered, 'g')
#plt.plot(df_t, z_filtered, 'b')
#plt.title("Beschleunigungswerte gefiltert")
#plt.xlabel("t[s]")
#plt.ylabel("a[m/s^2]")
#plt.show()

plt.plot(df_t, df_x)
plt.plot(df_t, x_filtered)
plt.show()

plt.plot(df_t, df_y)
plt.plot(df_t, y_filtered)
plt.show()

plt.plot(df_t, df_z)
plt.plot(df_t, z_filtered)
plt.show()

############# 100 Hz ####################
plt.plot(t_new, x_new_filtered, 'r')
plt.plot(t_new, y_new_filtered, 'g')
plt.plot(t_new, z_new_filtered, 'b')
plt.title("Beschleunigungswerte gefiltert/interpoliert")
plt.xlabel("t[s]")
plt.ylabel("a[m/s^2]")
plt.show()
# create numpy array
arr = np.array([t_new, x_new, y_new, z_new])
arr = np.transpose(arr)
# add columns for v
#out_arr = geek.hstack((in_arr1, in_arr2))
spalte = np.zeros((arr.shape[0],6),dtype = float)
arr=np.hstack((arr, spalte))

print(arr[3][1])
print (len(arr))
for x in range(1,len(arr)):
    arr[x][4] = arr[x-1][4] + arr[x][1]*0.01
    arr[x][5] = arr[x-1][5] + arr[x][4]*0.01 #+ 0.5*arr[x][1]*0.01*0.01
    arr[x][6] = arr[x-1][5] + 0.5*(arr[x-1][4] + arr[x][4])*0.01
plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,4], 'r')
plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,5], 'g')
#plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,1], 'b')
plt.title("Geschwindigkeit (rot) und zurückgelegte Strecke in x-Richtung (grün)")
plt.xlabel("t[s]")
plt.ylabel("v[m/s] und s[m]")
plt.show()


#def calc_v(acc):
#    # acc array 0..len_acc
#    for x in geek.nditer(b): 
#    print(x)
```

and I have written another program which both didn't work

```
"""
Created on Sun Feb 18 23:12:58 2024

@author: Scheffe
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import scipy.io.wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lowpass(data: np.ndarray, cutoff: float, sample_rate: float, poles: int = 5):
    sos = scipy.signal.butter(poles, cutoff, 'lowpass', fs=sample_rate, output='sos')
    filtered_data = scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
    return filtered_data

def analyzeOneFile(fileName, csv_sep, csv_dec):
    df =pd.read_csv(fileName, sep = csv_sep, decimal=csv_dec) 
    df.columns = ["t[s]", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"]
    df_t =  df['t[s]'] #df['Column1']
    df_x = df['Column2']
    df_y = df['Column3']
    df_z = df['Column4']
    
    df_x_cut = df_x[50:-50:]
    df_y_cut = df_y[50:-50:]
    df_z_cut = df_z[50:-50:]
    df_x_cut_mean = df_x_cut.mean()
    df_y_cut_mean = df_y_cut.mean()
    df_z_cut_mean = df_z_cut.mean()
    return df_x_cut_mean, df_y_cut_mean, df_z_cut_mean

def Filter(string, substr):
    # Create an empty list to store the filtered strings
    filtered_list = []
     
    # Loop over each string in the input list
    for s in string:
        # Loop over each substring in the filter list
        for sub in substr:
            # Check if the substring is in the current string
            if sub in s:
                # If it is, add the string to the filtered list and break out of the inner loop
                filtered_list.append(s)
                break
                 
    # Return the final filtered list
    return filtered_list

substr = ['.txt']

path = r"C:\Users\Scheffe\Desktop\test"

import os

a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []



files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Scheffe\Desktop\test")
files  = Filter(files, substr)
#files = [x for x in files if  ]
for file in files:
    # print(path+'\\'+file)
    aaa,bbb,ccc  = analyzeOneFile(path+'\\'+file,  ';', ",") 
    a_list.append(aaa) 
    b_list.append(bbb) 
    c_list.append(ccc) 
    print(str(aaa) + '  ' + str(bbb)  + '  ' + str(ccc))
    
plt.plot(a_list, 'r')
plt.plot(b_list, 'g')
plt.plot(c_list, 'b')
plt.grid()
plt.show()`
```

here is some of the data i used

```
0,021891;-0,009536;-0,000712;-0,146713;0,000000;
0,029926;0,000560;0,079622;-0,826018;0,000000;
0,037866;-0,077522;0,027200;-0,151405;0,000000;
0,046079;-0,126939;0,029154;0,313798;0,000000;
0,054595;-0,068681;0,071280;0,059369;0,000000;
0,061986;-0,068855;0,049971;-0,209205;0,000000;
0,070023;-0,123108;0,096733;-0,210235;0,000000;
0,078130;-0,137797;0,083957;0,047120;0,000000;
0,086215;-0,116401;0,084942;0,053283;0,000000;
0,094650;-0,070322;0,073869;-0,026208;0,000000;
0,103288;0,006295;0,042367;-0,107468;0,000000;
0,110057;-0,028803;0,077119;-0,205610;0,000000;
0,117910;-0,003446;0,086510;-0,167055;0,000000;
0,126163;-0,023975;0,102663;-0,035351;0,000000;
0,133825;-0,021058;0,113021;-0,006528;0,000000;
0,142237;0,022841;0,155508;-0,082463;0,000000;
0,150136;-0,043997;0,258787;-0,196797;0,000000;
0,157974;-0,129643;0,410454;-0,294212;0,000000;
0,165876;-0,041243;0,400606;-0,215762;0,000000;
0,173810;-0,021469;0,335369;-0,041549;0,000000;
0,181841;-0,036537;0,380739;0,094754;0,000000;
0,189762;0,051170;0,467109;-0,056748;0,000000;
0,197939;0,068128;0,495814;-0,207198;0,000000;
0,206087;0,091269;0,644888;-0,192350;0,000000;
0,213865;0,106122;0,852527;-0,087640;0,000000;
0,221898;0,084101;0,742442;-0,033399;0,000000;
0,230265;0,073656;0,153614;0,564511;0,000000;
0,238019;-0,112752;0,364325;0,273994;0,000000;
0,246682;-0,271099;0,064857;-0,888936;0,000000;
0,254148;-0,460533;0,475795;-0,469330;0,000000;
0,261774;-0,212366;0,394006;0,351722;0,000000;
0,269740;-1,517351;1,285191;0,528047;0,000000;
0,277742;-1,011518;1,125651;-0,472436;0,000000;
0,285901;-0,858340;1,287425;0,028574;0,000000;
0,294519;-0,039604;0,573058;1,857512;0,000000;
0,301926;-0,581536;0,704700;0,863084;0,000000;
0,310046;-0,381859;0,514256;-1,914023;0,000000;
0,318287;-1,441948;1,166754;-1,667295;0,000000;
0,325947;-1,211554;1,442319;0,955921;0,000000;
0,333687;-1,640915;0,950738;1,175983;0,000000;
0,341842;-1,711670;1,971392;0,194202;0,000000;
0,349944;-1,636239;2,006698;-1,134533;0,000000;
0,357912;-1,095724;1,212044;-0,375614;0,000000;
0,365891;-1,053277;1,672887;1,021967;0,000000;
0,373896;-1,738270;1,386784;0,710947;0,000000;
0,381770;-0,967698;1,079311;0,734626;0,000000;
0,390088;-0,946087;1,481303;0,021999;0,000000;
0,397916;-0,793875;1,191193;-0,424397;0,000000;
0,406475;-0,341653;0,675366;0,289680;0,000000;
0,414078;-1,171034;1,000116;0,111111;0,000000;
0,422113;-0,524395;0,451441;0,061755;0,000000;
0,429942;-0,654713;0,869705;-0,578921;0,000000;
0,437759;0,009279;-0,429063;-0,543916;0,000000;
0,445960;-0,503988;-0,657609;-0,270781;0,000000;
0,453914;-0,657437;-1,592680;-0,004784;0,000000;
0,462104;-0,663391;-1,268113;1,076712;0,000000;
0,469903;-0,002939;-1,413158;0,669127;0,000000;
0,477882;-0,208922;-1,390580;-0,307489;0,000000;
0,486692;0,306409;-2,082337;0,960526;0,000000;
0,494513;1,756081;-2,603852;3,012278;0,000000;
0,502211;1,318149;-2,876580;-0,176449;0,000000;
0,509972;1,834048;-3,130478;-1,164354;0,000000;
0,517979;2,797886;-4,619196;0,818024;0,000000;
0,526087;3,258480;-5,357902;1,371383;0,000000;
0,534252;3,691705;-4,981981;1,361875;0,000000;
0,542057;2,333251;-4,061619;-2,414371;0,000000;
0,550018;2,292371;-3,546837;-2,769035;0,000000;
0,557872;3,131391;-3,316120;0,216455;0,000000;
0,566430;0,493837;-2,499182;1,498643;0,000000;
0,574179;-0,276817;-1,630258;0,397717;0,000000;
0,582841;0,276054;-1,850277;-0,659911;0,000000;
0,590390;0,993683;-2,160106;-0,475127;0,000000;
0,597959;0,860085;-2,896910;0,638058;0,000000;
0,606405;0,735623;-3,384529;0,867208;0,000000;
0,614411;0,331859;-3,593135;0,038508;0,000000;
0,622300;1,172523;-3,395767;-0,345181;0,000000;
0,630345;0,764251;-4,049522;-1,085697;0,000000;
0,638309;1,331697;-3,298841;0,589730;0,000000;
0,646293;0,961778;-3,456444;1,202035;0,000000;
0,654090;0,884091;-2,919070;-0,679973;0,000000;
0,662067;1,902029;-2,662486;-0,861340;0,000000;
0,670451;1,429295;-2,636850;0,316391;0,000000;
0,678022;0,891136;-2,491861;0,578938;0,000000;
0,686313;1,041610;-2,912176;-0,398561;0,000000;
0,694032;1,119545;-2,968215;-0,518622;0,000000;
0,702145;0,853311;-2,748457;-0,011725;0,000000;
0,710115;0,326676;-2,311610;0,375109;0,000000;
0,718272;0,025120;-1,715642;0,213980;0,000000;
0,726892;-0,218778;-2,327560;-0,466409;0,000000;
0,734318;-0,078836;-1,849007;0,445513;0,000000;
0,742274;0,479671;-1,496385;0,609632;0,000000;
0,750241;-0,003134;-1,351039;-0,146695;0,000000;
0,758639;0,505319;-1,883820;0,175991;0,000000;
0,766241;-0,519614;-0,580615;0,344388;0,000000;
0,774088;-0,283102;-0,017453;0,181654;0,000000;
0,782184;-0,792056;0,279715;-0,923456;0,000000;
0,790331;-0,855855;0,625267;-0,814903;0,000000;
0,798202;-0,031118;0,250469;1,229400;0,000000;
0,806051;0,083503;-0,452860;0,025232;0,000000;
0,814033;-0,030326;-0,216426;-1,377520;0,000000;
0,822300;-0,338525;0,346690;-0,489298;0,000000;
0,830322;-0,228705;-0,627484;0,803095;0,000000;
0,838415;-0,177635;0,630068;0,949104;0,000000;
0,846619;-0,132258;0,530235;-0,786388;0,000000;
0,853845;-0,559448;0,542689;-0,851094;0,000000;
0,862304;0,289516;-0,175487;1,059420;0,000000;
0,870186;-0,104592;-0,041587;0,108985;0,000000;
0,878277;0,585782;-0,048418;-0,862802;0,000000;
0,886441;-0,053486;-0,112091;-0,977623;0,000000;
0,894268;-0,186846;-0,289636;0,513735;0,000000;
0,902302;0,141734;0,261876;0,865461;0,000000;
0,910027;0,031720;0,078778;-1,238750;0,000000;
0,918273;0,384165;0,679134;-1,250644;0,000000;
0,926056;-0,021632;0,592282;0,848821;0,000000;
0,934656;-0,068899;0,228184;2,328119;0,000000;
0,942428;0,050438;0,820378;-0,693347;0,000000;
0,950185;0,717390;0,703992;-2,239468;0,000000;
0,958401;0,556730;0,619673;-0,271119;0,000000;
0,967228;0,826999;0,348090;2,259063;0,000000;
0,974385;0,614233;0,413238;-0,355717;0,000000;
0,982204;-0,062492;0,664452;-2,131348;0,000000;
0,990324;0,158289;0,125655;-0,311879;0,000000;
0,998170;-0,876281;0,633822;1,344121;0,000000;
```

See above what I wrote

Comment: What does 'did not work' mean - did not run / gave error message / did not give expected output?

Comment: Didn't give the expected distances

Comment: The data isnt't all I have. The original data is about 60 seconds long (First column). I repeated the experiment about 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do this with an accelerometer.  There's a few reasons for this:

1)Accelerometers max out.  Accelerate too hard and you'll go over the maximum and be using the wrong numbers

2)The equation for distance includes a v_0 term- an initial velocity.  The accelerometer cannot account for this

3)Accelerometers are extremely inaccurate and noisy.  Even if left totally alone on a flat surface it will rarely read 0.  Which makes attempting to use it for location or distance a bad idea.

The best way to do this is to use fine location and get the difference between start and end locations.  Which will also have accuracy issues, but be FAR more accurate.

If you're in a well known area and can set up external hardware, placing some BLE beacons and using those for location tracking will be more accurate over short distances.  But it only works if you can set up the physical beacons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
The accelerometer isnt good in anyway. I will research the ideas you had for this task.